# Finding an example

Tags: real-analysis, probability, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for an example to have two distinct decreasing functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ between [0,1], such that their ratio ($\phi=\frac{g_1}{g_2}$) is a periodic function with period one, moreover for two distinct density function $f_1$ and $f_2$ the following equality holds, $f_1.g_1=f_2.g_2$.

Comment: Take $f_1 = f_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: I am looking for two distinct function. Thank you for mentioning that, I need to edit my question.

Comment: You can set $f_2 = \lambda f_1$ for some constant $\lambda$ and they will be distinct functions, but the ratio still constant.

Comment: yes, you are right, but I need some other kind of functions, since I need other equality to be hold. again thank you for correcting me, I need to edit my question much more.

Comment: I have tried the following example, $g_1(x)=\frac{1-(x-[x])}{[x]+1}$ and $g_2(x)=\frac{1}{[x]+1}$ and two arbitrary density function $f_1$ and $f_2$ which that equality $f_1.g_1=f_2.g_2$ holds, but unfortunately $g_1$ is not decreasing function.

Comment: By $[x]$ I mean the integer part of real value $x$.